# RubyMine has a communication error trying to create the SDK

Tags: ruby, windows, rubymine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Windows 10 with Windows Subsystem for Linux, where I installed Ubuntu, rbenv, and Ruby 2.6.3:

[image]

I then tried to connect RubyMine to this Ruby, but I get the error "Communication error", any ideas why:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From RubyMine [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2018.2/ruby-version-managers.html):

```
/home/pupeno/.rbenv/bin/rbenv
```

or

```
/usr/bin/rbenv
```